# Raincloud plot: change edge color and box color

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, violin-plot

I would like to modify my raincloud plot so that the boxplot has the same colors as the violins and so that the edges of the violins disappear or even have the same color as the filling, but less transparent. I assume I could somehow loop through the categories and have a list of colors to be used but ideally I'd like a simpler solution if possible.
I attached a picture of what I'd like the plot to look like (that one was created in ggplot and I can't find examples of this for python) and one of what my plot looks like now.
Here's the code so far:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,10))

ax = pt.half_violinplot( x = "atlas", y = "voxel_count", data =T, palette = 'inferno',
                        scale = "area",  inner = None)

ax = sns.stripplot( x = "atlas", y = "voxel_count", data = T,jitter=1 ,edgecolor = "white",palette='inferno',
                   size = 8,alpha=0.8)

ax=sns.boxplot(x="atlas", y="voxel_count",data =T,color = "black", width = .15, zorder = 10,
               showcaps = True, boxprops = {'facecolor':'none', "zorder":10},
               showfliers=True, whiskerprops = {'linewidth':2, "zorder":10},
               saturation = 1)
```

Example data: https://github.com/TanjaS91/Example_data

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your code seems to call a function `pt.half_violinplot` which isn't defined.

Comment: See e.g. [Can you have a box plot overlap a half violin plot on a raincloud plot using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376683/can-you-have-a-box-plot-overlap-a-half-violin-plot-on-a-raincloud-plot-using-pyt). Using the code from that post, you can set the `linewidth` of each violin to `0`.