# How to independently change the width of the raincloud in ptitprince.RainPlot()

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to create a Rainplot of my data, using the below code:

```
pt.RainCloud(x='Group', y=variable_to_plot, data=combined_data, palette=colors, orient = 'h', offset = 0.1,
             box_showfliers=False, width_box = 0.1,
             cloud_alpha=0.7, width_viol = 0.6,
             move = .2, rain_alpha = 0.002, jitter = 1)
```

In the docs for the function, it says that by using the prefix "rain*"* I can change the parameters of the individual plots* (as I do above with rain_alpha above). However, if I try to use rain_width, I get the error:

```
TypeError: ptitprince.PtitPrince.stripplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'width'
```

This makes sense because if I go into the code it says, that the width of the rain plot is initialised as width= width_box, which is defined already when I try to run the code.

Is there a way around this? I have a lot of points to include in the scatter plot, so having the rainplot set to its default width makes it impossible to see the individual points, or even a good sense of them overall, so I'd like to make this graph a bigger part of my overall figure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried setting the width of the rain plot using rain_width

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand without images and without test data.  Maybe this post [Can you have a box plot overlap a half violin plot on a raincloud plot using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376683/can-you-have-a-box-plot-overlap-a-half-violin-plot-on-a-raincloud-plot-using-pyt) is of interest? Or maybe add an issue at the [RainCloudPlot github](https://github.com/RainCloudPlots/RainCloudPlots/issues)?